# What to do with zombie Kafka consumers after a rebalance?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I did a little experiment that shows when using a batch consumer. Old message could overwrite new messages when rebalancing.

Consumer1 with 30s `max-poll-interval`:

```java
    @KafkaListener(id = "t1", topics = "test", batch = "true")
    public void listen(List<String> records) throws InterruptedException {
        // mimic gc
        LOGGER.info("received size {}", records.size());
        Thread.sleep(80000L);
        // processed 1 record and died
        LOGGER.info("processed {}", records.get(0));
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Consumer2 that handles normally:

```java
    @KafkaListener(id = "t1", topics = "test", batch = "true")
    public void listen(List<String> records) throws InterruptedException {
        for (String record : records) {
            LOGGER.info("processed {}", record);
        }
    }
```

- Before both consumers start, send 2 record into the topic with value 1 and 2 respectively.
- Then start consumer1
- When `received size 2` was logged, start consumer2
- consumer1 leaves the group because of sleep time exceed `max-poll-interval`
- consumer2 takes over the partition. And processed record 1 and 2
- consumer1 wakeup from sleep and process record 1 and died.
- The last record processed was 1.

Following was logs of both consumer:
consumer1:

```
2022-07-07 10:28:13.025|[]|t1-0-C-1|INFO |TestRecordHandler.java:55|received size 2
2022-07-07 10:28:28.012|[]|kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | t1|INFO |AbstractCoordinator.java:988|[Consumer clientId=consumer-t1-7, groupId=t1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing
2022-07-07 10:28:31.076|[]|kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | t1|INFO |AbstractCoordinator.java:988|[Consumer clientId=consumer-t1-7, groupId=t1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing
2022-07-07 10:28:34.149|[]|kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | t1|INFO |AbstractCoordinator.java:988|[Consumer clientId=consumer-t1-7, groupId=t1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing
2022-07-07 10:28:37.224|[]|kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | t1|INFO |AbstractCoordinator.java:988|[Consumer clientId=consumer-t1-7, groupId=t1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing
2022-07-07 10:28:40.293|[]|kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | t1|INFO |AbstractCoordinator.java:988|[Consumer clientId=consumer-t1-7, groupId=t1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing
2022-07-07 10:28:43.031|[]|kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | t1|WARN |AbstractCoordinator.java:1396|[Consumer clientId=consumer-t1-7, groupId=t1] consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
2022-07-07 10:28:43.031|[]|kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | t1|INFO |AbstractCoordinator.java:1048|[Consumer clientId=consumer-t1-7, groupId=t1] Member consumer-t1-7-a26e8418-3ff8-46b3-8152-17dbe88b620a sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator 100.85.230.15:9095 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired.
2022-07-07 10:28:43.033|[]|kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | t1|INFO |AbstractCoordinator.java:966|[Consumer clientId=consumer-t1-7, groupId=t1] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-07-07 10:28:43.033|[]|kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | t1|INFO |AbstractCoordinator.java:988|[Consumer clientId=consumer-t1-7, groupId=t1] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-07-07 10:29:33.028|[]|t1-0-C-1|INFO |TestRecordHandler.java:57|processed 1
```

consumer2:

```
2022-07-07 10:29:25.296|[]|t1-0-C-1|INFO |LogAccessor.java:292|t1: partitions assigned: [test-1, test-0, test-2]
2022-07-07 10:29:25.830|[]|t1-0-C-1|INFO |TestRecordHandler.java:87|processed 1
2022-07-07 10:29:25.830|[]|t1-0-C-1|INFO |TestRecordHandler.java:87|processed 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Thread.sleep(80000)` (which I guess is a metaphor for a long running process) is actually breaking the contract that say that at any point in time, there should be only one consumer (alive) per topic partition withing that consumer group.

As far as Kafka is concerned, this is true in your test: consumer 1 is considered dead since it missed its timeout, and the sole (valid) consumer is now consumer 2. If consumer 1 was trying to interact with the Kafka cluster at that point, most actions would fails since it's no longer registered to those partitions.

When consumer 1 comes turns out to actually be alive after 80s, it's behaving like a zombie: the Kafka cluster considers it dead although it still does stuff with the data it has read previously and kept in memory. You don't want that to happen.

What you want it to do instead is to discard its data and die. One way to do that in Spring I think is to implement `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` and react to `onPartitionsRevoked​`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener.html

Another way is to make sure `max-poll-interval` is always large enough to cater for the duration of the long processing, by time-boxing the duration of the lengthy process and by setting `max-poll-interval` to some value larger than that.

Zombie are a common problems in distributed systems: on the other side of the network, there is no way to distinguish an application that takes very long to respond from one that is gone forever due to crash/network issue/k8s restarting it/... so timeout and is pretty much the main tool we have, and we should make sure zombie kill themselves for system to converge to a healthy state.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if there is a configuration that revoked partition will not be assigned to other consumers in like 30s. And we just need to assure that we kill that zombie consumer in 30s.

Comment: I indeed don't think there's such a parameter. 
BTW the Spring `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` is actually plugged to the Kafka client's own `ConsumerRebalanceListener`. Here is the doc for it, with detailed explanations about the guarantees we have on the order in which the various methods are called:
https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html